# Having a single _viewstart and web.config when using areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

Is it possible to have a single _viewtstart.cshtml and web.config file when using areas in MVC3. I'm finding that I need to have the _viewstart.cshtml and web.config replicated in every area. This seems rather daft especially with the _viewstart file.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but can you use the absolute path? `"~/Views/Shared/_viewStart.cshtml"`

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options:

- Move the _viewStart to the root of your site
- Or - put in a pre-build event to copy the _viewStart to the areas

HTH.